# MYSQL query takes a long time to load

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have the following query that although it works it takes a very long time to load

```
SELECT name, t1.*
FROM user, driver_tracker t1 
LEFT JOIN driver_tracker t2
ON (t1.phone = t2.phone AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE user.phone = t1.phone
AND companyid = 'asus'
AND t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Indexes? Table structure? Explain plan? An explanation of the contradictory logic in the join and filter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query properly expressed:

```
SELECT u.name, t1.*
FROM user u JOIN
     driver_tracker t1 
     ON u.phone = t1.phone LEFT JOIN
     driver_tracker t2
     ON (t1.phone = t2.phone AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE u.companyid = 'asus' AND t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY name;
```

(Note the replacement of the comma in the `from` clause with a proper explicit join.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.)

Recommended indexes:  `user(companyid, phone, name)` and `driver_tracker(phone, id)`.